# REGEX: extract different types of house numbers from string (address) using stringr

Tags: r, regex, stringr

This is a dataset (one column) with various street entries, where the house numbers can occur in different positions, combinations and lengths. I aim to separate street name and house number and have come this far with regex:

```
regex <- "[[:digit:]]{1,}[[:punct:]]?\\s?[-0-9]{0,}[A-z]{0,2}\\b"
streets <- data.frame(STR_orig = c("StreetA 11-13", 
                           "StreetB 100", 
                           "StreetC 25a",
                           "12 StreetD",
                           "13 StreetE WE",
                           "StreetF 81A+B",
                           "StreetG 1,2,3",
                           "StreetH 1, 2, 3",
                           "StreetI 8/9",
                           "StreetJ 11 - 13"))
streets <- streets %>%
    mutate(STR = gsub(regex, "\\1", STR_orig), 
    NR = stri_extract_all(STR_orig, regex=regex))
```

i.e.

```
> streets
          STR_orig         STR      NR
1    StreetA 11-13    StreetA    11-13
2      StreetB 100    StreetB      100
3      StreetC 25a    StreetC      25a
4       12 StreetD     StreetD     12 
5    13 StreetE WE  StreetE WE     13 
6    StreetE 13 WE    StreetE    13 WE
7    StreetF 81A+B  StreetF +B     81A
8    StreetG 1,2,3   StreetG ,  1,2, 3
9  StreetH 1, 2, 3  StreetH ,  1, 2, 3
10     StreetI 8/9    StreetI      8/9
11 StreetJ 11 - 13 StreetJ  -   11, 13
```

Still I don't catch the + in 81A+B, the - after StreetJ is not deleted and the space sometimes remains. It may also happen that points like WE, N and others are indicated.

What do I have to change in my regex to solve this properly? I've tried so much already... Thanks for any advice!

P.S.: Currently the output is a list where it is not quite clear to me when elements get seperated, see case 8 and 9. Additionally I would also be interested in merging the list elements to one chr entry (unlist doesn't work?).

Edited:

Desired output could be

```
          STR_orig         STR      NR
1    StreetA 11-13     StreetA   11-13 ## w/o space chr
2      StreetB 100     StreetB     100 
3      StreetC 25a     StreetC     25a 
4       12 StreetD     StreetD      12
5    13 StreetE WE     StreetE   13 WE
6    StreetE 13 WE     StreetE   13 WE
7    StreetF 81A+B     StreetF   81A+B
8    StreetG 1,2,3     StreetG   1,2,3
9  StreetH 1, 2, 3     StreetH 1, 2, 3
10     StreetI 8/9     StreetI     8/9
11 StreetJ 11 - 13     StreetJ 11 - 13
```

Comment: I as a human probably wouldn't be able to complete the task you request. How is `StreetG 1,2,3` even a street number? Unless you have a clear definition of what exactly a street number is in words, it's going to be difficult to write a regex to do it for you. What exactly is the desired result?

Comment: I understand the problem. There are entries that specify "1 - 7" as the house number and others that write "STR. 85, 87, 89" (because only the odd numbers lay on this side of the street). There is even an entry that reads "10,12,13 AND 14".
My idea was that the entries should start with a number and everything that follows (character combinations with punctuations + - /, max. 2 letters, etc.) should be extracted as house number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `base R`, where `gsub()` is used. Maybe you can use the code below to get the desired output:

```
streets$STR <- gsub(".*?(Street\\w).*","\\1",streets$STR_orig)
streets$NR <- gsub("(.*?)Street\\w\\s(.*)","\\1\\2",streets$STR_orig)
```

such that

```
> streets
          STR_orig     STR         NR
1    StreetA 11-13 StreetA      11-13
2      StreetB 100 StreetB        100
3      StreetC 25a StreetC        25a
4       12 StreetD StreetD 12 StreetD
5    13 StreetE WE StreetE      13 WE
6    StreetF 81A+B StreetF      81A+B
7    StreetG 1,2,3 StreetG      1,2,3
8  StreetH 1, 2, 3 StreetH    1, 2, 3
9      StreetI 8/9 StreetI        8/9
10 StreetJ 11 - 13 StreetJ    11 - 13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look for all names without number and than take the longest name, assuming that this is the street name, and write it in column `STR`. Then `sub` `STR` from `STR_orig` to get the `NR`.

```
streets$STR <- lapply(
 regmatches(streets$STR_orig,  gregexpr("[[:alpha:]]+", streets$STR_orig))
 , function(x)  x[which.max(lapply(x, nchar))])
streets$NR <- apply(streets, 1, function(x) trimws(sub(x[2], "", x[1])))
streets
#          STR_orig     STR      NR
#1    StreetA 11-13 StreetA   11-13
#2      StreetB 100 StreetB     100
#3      StreetC 25a StreetC     25a
#4       12 StreetD StreetD      12
#5    13 StreetE WE StreetE  13  WE
#6    StreetF 81A+B StreetF   81A+B
#7    StreetG 1,2,3 StreetG   1,2,3
#8  StreetH 1, 2, 3 StreetH 1, 2, 3
#9      StreetI 8/9 StreetI     8/9
#10 StreetJ 11 - 13 StreetJ 11 - 13
```